# Four triggers: It does not work

Tags: triggers, subquery

[image]

Hello everybody,
excuse me for my bad english
It's been more than 4 days I am trying to solve my problem:
each trigger works well but when I combine them there is an error:
`the subquery returns more than 1 value`.

I tried to follow all the tips in this website and others, I could not make it works, though.
the concerned tables are: PIECES, COMPOSITIONSGAMMES, nomenclatures and SITUATIONS.
What I want the triggers to do is :

1. When the user inserts a new row on "SITUATIONS" and if 'nomstrategie'= "DST" (It's a name of a strategy but this detail does not really matter, I mean for people who will help me), I need other rows to be inserted with the same reference (referencepiece), the same strategy(nomstrategie). Only 'ancienposte' and 'nouveauposte' have to change. Indeed, the first one's value(s) has to be all 'Numeroposte' from the table "Compositionsgammes". The second one's value has to be '???'.
2. I need, when I insert a new row and 'nomstrategie'='DST', other rows to be inserted with all 'piecesfilles' in the table "Nomenclatures"
   of the reference 'referencepiece' in the row inserted by the user. And in 'ancienposte', there should be 'numeroposte' in the table "compositionsgammes".
3. I need, when the user inserts a new row and 'nomstrategie'= 'delestage, another row to be inserted as below, for example :

   inserted row: Ref A           ancienposte : P01         Nouveauposte :P02      Nomstrategie :Delestage…………

   row to be inserted: Ref A          ancienposte : P02         Nouveauposte :NULL    Nomstrategie :Delestage…………
4. I need, for every row in the table "situations", calculate a value called 'charge' in the table situations charge=(TS/Taillelot)+Tu

here are the triggers I've done:

```
create trigger [dbo].[ALLDST]
ON [dbo].[SITUATIONS]
AFTER INSERT /*pas d'update*/
as 
        begin
        set nocount on
            insert into SITUATIONS(ReferencePiece,nomstrategie,AncienPoste,nouveauposte,DateStrategie)
            select distinct i.referencepiece, i.nomstrategie,COMPOSITIONSGAMMES.NumeroPoste,'???',i.DateStrategie

            from inserted i, PIECES, compositionsgammes, SITUATIONS s
            where i.ReferencePiece is not null 
            and i.NomStrategie='DST' 
            and i.ReferencePiece=pieces.ReferencePiece and pieces.CodeGamme=COMPOSITIONSGAMMES.CodeGamme 
            and i.AncienPoste<>COMPOSITIONSGAMMES.NumeroPoste
            and i.DateStrategie=s.DateStrategie

            end



create trigger [dbo].[Calcul_Charge]
on [charges].[dbo].[SITUATIONS]
after insert 
as
begin


update situations

set charge= (select (cg.TS/pieces.TailleLot)+cg.tu from situations s
inner join COMPOSITIONSGAMMES cg on cg.NumeroPoste=SITUATIONS.AncienPoste
inner join pieces on SITUATIONS.ReferencePiece=pieces.ReferencePiece 
inner join inserted i on s.DateStrategie=i.DateStrategie
where cg.CodeGamme=pieces.CodeGamme and NumeroPoste=situations.AncienPoste
)   

end


create trigger [dbo].[Duplicate_SITUATIONS]
ON [dbo].[SITUATIONS]
AFTER INSERT
as 
        begin
        set nocount on
        declare @ref varchar(50)
        declare @strategie varchar(50)
        declare @ancienposte varchar(50)
        declare @datestrategie date
        declare @pourcentage decimal(18,3)
        declare @coeff decimal(18,3)
        declare @charge decimal(18,3)
        /*while (select referencepiece from situations where ReferencePiece)  is not null*/
            select @ref=referencepiece, @strategie=nomstrategie,@ancienposte=NouveauPoste,
            @datestrategie=datestrategie, @pourcentage=PourcentageStrategie,@coeff=coeffameliorationposte,@charge=charge
            from inserted,POSTESDECHARGE 
            where ReferencePiece is not null
            and POSTESDECHARGE.NumeroPoste = inserted.AncienPoste
            if @strategie = 'delestage' and @ancienposte is not null
            /*if GETDATE()>= (select datestrategie from SITUATIONS)*/
            begin
            insert into SITUATIONS(ReferencePiece, nomstrategie,AncienPoste,DateStrategie,
            StatutStrategie,DateModification,PourcentageStrategie,charge)
            values
            (@ref, @strategie, @ancienposte, @datestrategie,1,getdate(),@pourcentage,@charge*@coeff)
            end
            end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm mostly familiar with T-SQL (MS SQL), not sure if this will work for your case.. but I usually avoid updates using a sub query and rewrite your update:

```
update situations

set charge= (select (cg.TS/pieces.TailleLot)+cg.tu from situations s
inner join COMPOSITIONSGAMMES cg on cg.NumeroPoste=SITUATIONS.AncienPoste
inner join pieces on SITUATIONS.ReferencePiece=pieces.ReferencePiece 
inner join inserted i on s.DateStrategie=i.DateStrategie
where cg.CodeGamme=pieces.CodeGamme and NumeroPoste=situations.AncienPoste
)
```

as follows

```
update s set 
    charge= (cg.TS/pieces.TailleLot)+cg.tu
from situations s
    inner join COMPOSITIONSGAMMES cg on cg.NumeroPoste=SITUATIONS.AncienPoste
    inner join pieces on SITUATIONS.ReferencePiece=pieces.ReferencePiece 
    inner join inserted i on s.DateStrategie=i.DateStrategie
where cg.CodeGamme=pieces.CodeGamme and NumeroPoste=situations.AncienPoste
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked but didn't completely solve the problem.
I have a question: your request is very similar to mine. what is the real difference between them? 
Thank you again

Comment: I'm not using a sub query to get the value for a field, this will update multiple rows if there are multiple rows matching the criteria.